Best Practices for Storing access_token and refresh_token in Web Applications
I'm working on a web application and considering different methods for storing access_token and refresh_token. I'm looking for advice on the best approach to handle token storage and refresh logic securely. Here are the methods I'm considering:
Method 1: Store Both access_token and refresh_token on Client-Side with Secure Cookies
Description:

Store both access_token and refresh_token as HttpOnly, Secure cookies with SameSite=Strict.
Once the access_token expires, retrieve the refresh_token from the client-side cookie to obtain a new access_token.

Method 2: Store access_token in Local Storage and refresh_token in Backend Database
Description:

Store the access_token in local storage with an embedded expiration time.
Store the refresh_token in the backend database.
Use the refresh_token from the backend to issue a new access_token when needed.

Method 3: Store access_token in Cookies with Extended Expiry and Embedded Expiration Time
Description:

Store the access_token in an HttpOnly, Secure cookie with a long expiration time, synchronized with the refresh_token expiration.
Embed the actual expiration time within the access_token itself.
This approach helps distinguish between an expired cookie(as you know if a cookies is expired , it will get removed from the request header) and a user who has never logged in.


Questions

Security: How can I ensure the security of the refresh_token if stored client-side?
Best Practice: Which of these methods is considered the best practice for modern web applications and why?
Alternatives: Are there any alternative approaches or improvements to these methods that can provide better security and usability?


Please have a look at [ask]. Questions should focus on one thing, furthermore this question will only lead to opinionated answers making the question off-topic for SO

I removed my thoughts, is their have anything else I should notice ?
